# Process SSAS OLAP cube via Python

Tags: python, ssas, olap, olap-cube, xmla

I have an OLAP cube on SSAS (and XMLA script for processing).
How can I call processing it via Python script?
The only things I can find are about getting data from cubes (mdx/etc), and some popular libraries are really old (for example, xmla was last updated in 2013).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For loading pd df with mdx query you can use mdx-to-pd. You will provide the mdx query and connection and it will return the dataframe
you will need powerbi installed and you will need to have access to cube

```
from mdx_to_pd import mdx_retriever

connection = "Data Source=https://biserver.company.com/database/;Catalog=Model;"
query = """
        SELECT NON EMPTY [Measures].[Order Count] ON COLUMNS,
        NON EMPTY ([Markets].[Country].[Country]) ON ROWS
        FROM [OLAP_CUBE]
        """
# returns pd.DataFrame()

df = mdx_retriever(query, connection)
```